# About recording Kinect data in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, motion

I am using [Zigfu](http://zigfu.com/en/zdk/unity3d/)+Kinect+Unity3D for collecting the motion data.

I studied some scripts and searched some information online but still failed.

What I want to do is to record the motion data and save into a txt file (or oni, bvh is fine), then can do the playback next time.
In addition, I hope that it can build in webplayer platform.

Any solutions or suggestions are appreciated.
And if someone can teach me how to use OpenNI's API for doing this, that will be great!

btw I notice that older version of Zigfu (in [Legacy](http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/legacy/)) actually save the data into json format(OpenNiSkeletion.cs).
However, it has been removed in the newest Zigfu.....